# JS não funciona depois de rodar o "npm run dev"

Tags: laravel, node.js, npm

Boa tarde,
estou estudando o Laravel 5.7 e estava querendo usar um plugin chamado [progressbar.js](https://progressbarjs.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.0/).
Uma das maneiras de instalar o plugin, é jogando o arquivo `progressbar.js` direto no `public/js` do Laravel, após isso, escrevo onde quero que o efeito se aplica, ex:

```
var bar = new ProgressBar.Path('#LoadingDiv', {
  easing: 'easeInOut',
  duration: 2400
});

bar.set(0);
bar.animate(1.0);  // Number from 0.0 to 1.0
```

E o teste de efeito funciona normalmente...

Mas creio que isso não é uma boa pratica, então resolvi apelar para o `npm` do `node.js`.

Conforme a documentação do plugin, rodei `npm install progressbar.js`(a instalação é feita com sucesso), depois disso vou no `webpack.mix.js` para utilizar o `laravel-mix` do Laravel, adiciono o que quero que o `laravel-mix` copie pra min no `public` do Laravel:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

 mix.js(...)
    .js("node_modules/progressbar.js/dist/progressbar.js", 'public/js')
    .sass(...);
```

Rodo o `npm run dev`, até aqui, ok! arquivo copiado para o public do Laravel com sucesso... 
Vou no meu arquivo do `app.blade.php` adiciono o script no mesmo lugar do antigo(que está funcionando), da meneira que acho correta:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/progressbar.js') }}" defer></script>
```

E pronto! Erro:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ProgressBar is not defined
    at onLoad ((index):74)
onLoad @ (index):74
load (async)
(anonymous) @ (index):73
```

Uma coisa que eu percebi, é que depois que usei o `laravel-mix` o script deu uma mudada, não sei falar no que influenciou a mudança, mas deu para notar que influenciou rsrs... Como o script é bem grande, não consigo exibir aqui para vocês...

Bom, alguém sabe o que estou fazendo de errado? Acho que estou fazendo algo de errado no processo...

**Edit**

Subi o projeto no GitHub para vocês darem uma olhada... 
[Repositório GitHub](https://github.com/Ursones/RW-Site)

Comment: rode o seguinte comando e informe qual foi o resultado da execução após isso: `npm install progressbar.js -- save`

Comment: Olá amigo, você fez importou o ProgressBar? Usando: `var ProgressBar = require('progressbar.js');`

Comment: @Sorack Rodei, deu uma modificada no código, deixei o link do repositório Git para você dar uma olhada...

Comment: @matheussoareslacerda deu a seguinte msg "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at (index):108"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, olhando seu projeto achei os problemas amigo...

#### Importando Bibliotecas Javascript

---

No arquivo localizado em

```
/RW-Site/resources/js/app.js
```

é onde você deve importar as bibliotecas que você instalou utilizando o npm.

Lá você pode observar que ele faz essa importação

```
require('./bootstrap');
```

No qual ele importa um arquivo localizado na mesma pasta, esse arquivo contem todas as configurações necessárias do bootstrap, incluindo o jQuery, popper e entre outros.

Sabendo disso agora basta criar um arquivo pra configurar as suas dependências, na minha maquina eu criei um arquivo: `progress.js` na mesma pasta do `app.js` e `bootstrap.js`, neste arquivo em simplesmente coloquei:

```
// Loading progressbar.js

window.ProgressBar = require('progressbar.js')
```

e depois, no `app.js` eu importei o arquivo que acabamos de criar, ficando:

```
require('./bootstrap');
require('./progress.js');
```

> **LEMBRAR:** No arquivo `app.blade.php` eu removi a linha que faz o require do
>   ProgressBar, pois não é preciso.

E no mesmo arquivo, lá no cabeçalho apenas importei:

`<script src="{!! mix('js/app.js') !!}"></script>`

> Com isso você deixa que o *webpack* configure e builde os seus *javascripts*, e você importa apenas sua app.js compilado.

lembre-se de remover esses 3 scripts:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/progressbar.js') }}"></script>
```

#### Reiniciando aplicação

---

Pronto, depois disso basta reiniciar sua aplicação, buildar ela para que os arquivos sejam compilados e *voilà*.

Aconselho utilizar o

```
npm run watch-poll
```

Assim suas alteração são refletidas automaticamente...

Fontes:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45125009/how-import-a-external-js-library-in-laravel

Comment: Valeu amigo, agora eu entendi onde estava errando...